# How to make a spline chart into pdf reports

Tags: pdf, charts, jasper-reports, spline

i have a Line Chart on my report (pdf) using (x,y) values from a dataset, the report shows the line chart correctly however i want to show this with a spline render or something like.

Comment: No my friend, it works very well, the chart shows the points and the line, but i want to plot with a spline chart not a xyline chart.

Comment: I have this http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_8853342nueva-imagen-7.png

Comment: And I want this http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_8853351nueva-imagen-6.png

Comment: And what makes you think that a "line chart" is a "spline chart"?

Comment: no, it just an example that i have this chart, i need spline chart but i can't find it on ireport. I'm asking if there is some way to get the spline chart of it...Is not necesary to be a jerk man, i'm asking for help or ideas no offending

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tried to use it myself, but i suppose `Time Series` chart type should do what you require (and, after a quick look, it seems JasperReports support this chart type). Anyways, if it doesn't, here is an example to resolve this by means of drawing a [Bezier line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456155/reporting-trend-line) to customize the chart.

Comment: sorry, this is unuseful to me, see i want a spline chart no a time series, no bezier line. but thank you anyway